# FireHbbtv extension by Firefox

Tags: firefox, sdk, hbbtv

I am learning to build a web application for Hbbtv using the Hbbtv SDK.
So for testing a sample app, I was looking for an emulator and came across FireHbbtv Extension by firefox.
However, whatever I do, it says the extension is not compatible with the version of Firefox. can any of you help with what is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firehbbtv extension is abandoned, but you can install it using an old Firefox version (<52 as far I remember). Make sure the automatic updates are disabled if you want to keep the extension available.

There is another HbbTV plugin named hybridTV (https://github.com/karl-rousseau/HybridTvViewer) It works fine, but it is in development.

There is also a third option, using the opera (now called vewd) SDK. You can find the info and the virtual machine downloads visiting
https://www.vewd.com/products-services/vewd-tv-emulator/

Comment: Sure! But personally I prefer Firehbbtv to develop apps, due it is faster than use the virtual machine. If you need to create opera (vewd) compatible smarttv apps or just test your HbbTV in opera environment you should use it